# What features to look for in a SharePoint host

Tags: web-hosting

I have a friend who is looking for SharePoint hosting (free is nice) for a not-for-profit orgranization.

She is considering http://myhosting.com and http://sharepointhosting.com.

I know very little about SharePoint, so I'm looking for advice on what features to look for in a host.

Also, comments on the two being considered are welcome, as well as recommendations for any others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used sharepointhosting's Dedicated Service by a costumer (before we changed to a more flexible linux solution... SCNR :-)).  The Service was very nice: Fast and flexible support, (a hardware defect was fixed within 2h), full access to all snapshots (don't know if this only available for the Dedicated Service) and many more. The price is also competitive and most hosters/providers makes special prices for NPO's. Just question the sales team (If they don't provide special plans for NPO's i would search for another provider).

For which features you have to look, i can't say. But i would say every service plan from sharepointhosting fits all your basic claims (just take a look at feature list and ask your friend if this fits the needs).

It's difficult to say "yes, thats enough for all you need" because every individual/organization has other structures and needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a cheaper, alternative hosted sharepoint solutions, please take a look at [asphostcentral.com](http://www.asphostcentral.com/Windows-Sharepoint-2010-Hosting.aspx). Things worth considering when selecting a sharepoint host:

1. Price (in terms of monthly dollars you have to spend)
2. Features (in terms of disk space and bandwidth you can use)
3. Functionality (in terms of things you can and cannot do when installing a sharepoint service on a particular server)
4. Support Response (in terms on how fast can a host response to your questions should you have problems)
5. Knowledge (in terms of how capable does your hosting fullfil their offers)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft themselves now offer Sharepoint hosting

You can check them out

http://www.microsoft.com/online/